# Is it possible to run Heroku toolbelt commands from the server via cron/scheduler (e.g. in a rake task or shell script)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, scheduler, heroku-toolbelt

I would like to run Heroku toolbelt command on the server in a scheduled way:

e.g.

```
heroku maintenance:on
# do some other stuff 
heroku maintenance:off
```

As far as I could find, there does not seem to be a way to do this, not even a workaround?

Comment: Is it an option to set up a cron job on your own machine to do this?  AFAIK the toolbelt commands are usually executed on a remote machine (ie the dev's machine) rather than on the actual heroku VPS.

Comment: "on my own machine" -> that is on my dev machine?  Not really practical and not reliable...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler) and configure the following command:

```
curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz \
 | tar xz && ./heroku-client/bin/heroku maintenance:on -a you-app-name-here
```

For this to work, you need to add a Config Variable named `HEROKU_API_KEY` and set its value to the "API Key" value from your Accounts page.